# Running <jdbc:initialize-database> at the beginning of context creation

Tags: java, spring, properties

I need to execute `SQL` script before `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` is initialized in Spring's context, as soon as application properties are stored in the database and this script should insert them. But currently placeholder is initialized earlier, which leads to errors.

Is there a way to execute `<jdbc:initialize-database data-source="dataSource" ...` before `<bean id="placeholderConfig" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer" ...` in Spring?

Or is there a way to initialize `placeholderConfig` bean later? I tried to use `depends-on`, `lazy-init` attributes for this bean, but it didn't help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is not directly possible because PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer implements BeanFactoryPostProcessor which makes this to be initialized early. You will have to think about alternatives.

Comment: Implement your own BeanFactoryPostProcessor which execute the SQL script and use the <property name="order" value="1"/> to set the order accordingly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is how I solved that. I created a class `Initializer`. This class in its constructor executes plain old sql statements (`java.sql.Statement`), creates table (if it doesn't exist), and inserts properties (if they are not there). The `dataSource` bean is passed in the context to this constructor, and `placeholderConfig` bean uses `depends-on="initializerBean"`. So, properties appear in the database before they are used.

Answer (score 6):

Another solution without creating any Bean:
If you've got one `<jdbc:initialize-database />` you can add this property `depends-on="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.DataSourceInitializer#0"` to your bean `<bean id="placeholderConfig" />`

If you have more than one `<jdbc:initialize-database />` adapt the `#0`.

Answer (score 3):

This script

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc">


    <jdbc:initialize-database data-source="dataSource">
        <jdbc:script location="classpath:database/drop_schema.sql" />
        <jdbc:script location="classpath:database/create_schema.sql" />
        <jdbc:script location="classpath:database/sample_data.sql"/>
    </jdbc:initialize-database>
    <!-- Other bean definitions -->
</bean>
```

is essentially a shortcut to

```
<bean class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.DataSourceInitializer" id="dataSourceInitializer">
    <property name="databasePopulator" ref="resourceDatabasePopulator"/>
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>
<bean id="resourceDatabasePopulator"
      class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ResourceDatabasePopulator">
    <property name="scripts">
        <array>
            <value>classpath:database/drop_schema.sql</value>
            <value>classpath:database/create_schema.sql</value>
            <value>classpath:database/sample_data.sql</value>
        </array>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Note that I've added id to the DataSourceInitializer bean. Now you can reference it in PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer's `depends-on` attribute. That way you declare that your PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer should be created after DataSourceInitializer.

```
<bean id="placeholderConfig" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer" depends-on="dataSourceInitializer"/>
```

In my case db was initialized after the LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean had been created and Hibernate was unable to validate my schema.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation explains how to deal with these problems:
http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.0.RC3/reference/html/ch12s09.html

```
12.9.1.1 Initialization of Other Components that Depend on the Database
```

Answer (score 0):

Our use case was arguably even more complex. We're using [flyway](http://flywaydb.org/) for database migrations and it needs to be started before the `entityManagerFactory` is created. The problem for us was that `<jdbc:initialize-database />` was only used in our migration tests and thus initialized in a different application context than `flyway` and the `entityManagerFactory`. So we couldn't simply use [L. BIZE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21428833/398441) answer and let our `flyway` bean depend on `org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.DataSourceInitializer#0` because it might not exist (i.e. in production it doesn't exist). We ended up creating a custom factory bean like this:

```
class OptionalBeanInitializer extends AbstractFactoryBean implements BeanFactoryAware {
    private String beanName;
    private BeanFactory beanFactory;

    @Override
    public void setBeanFactory(BeanFactory beanFactory) throws BeansException {
        this.beanFactory = beanFactory;
    }

    @Override
    public Class<?> getObjectType() {
        return OptionalBeanInitializer.class;
    }

    public void setBeanName(String beanName) {
        this.beanName = beanName;
    }

    @Override
    protected Object createInstance() throws Exception {
        if (beanFactory.containsBean(beanName)) {
            // Initialize
            beanFactory.getBean(beanName);
        }
        return new OptionalBeanInitializer();
    }
}
```

Which we could use to depend on our optional dependency like this:

```
<bean id="optionalDataSourceInitializer" class="com.x.y.z.OptionalBeanInitializer">
       <property name="beanName" value="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.DataSourceInitializer#0"/>
</bean>   

 <bean id="flyway" class="com.googlecode.flyway.core.Flyway" init-method="migrate" depends-on="optionalDataSourceInitializer">
       <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
 </bean>

 <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean" id="entityManagerFactory"
          depends-on="flyway, optionalDataSourceInitializer">
       <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
 </bean>
```

The `OptionalBeanInitializer` will take care of initializing the `org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.DataSourceInitializer#0` bean *only* if it exists.

Answer (score 0):

There are two simpler ways to add the depend-on attribute only for test context, and not for production context.

1/Override the bean in the test context.
In our case here is the production context :

```
<bean id="placeholderConfig" />
```

And the unit test context :

```
<bean id="placeholderConfig" depends-on="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.DataSourceInitializer#0" />
```

Make sure that the unit test context is loaded before the production context and the good placeholderConfig bean will be instanciated, after the jdbc:initialize-database phase.

2/Another way is to use profiles

```
<beans profile="!test">
    <bean id="placeholderConfig" .../>
</beans>
<beans profile="test">
    <jdbc:initialize-database data-source="dataSource" .../>
    <bean id="placeholderConfig" depends-on="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.DataSourceInitializer#0" .../>
</beans>
```